# File upload works in Firefox but shows exception in IE using spring

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, internet-explorer-9, forms, http-post

I have file upload in spring mvc it works fine in firefox but throws the following exception in `IE9`

```
  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

this is what is my form  :

this is what is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Regional_WhseFormAddSave", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView CIMtrek_Regional_Whse(
            @RequestParam("CIMtrek_xmlData") String CIMtrek_xmlData,
            @RequestParam("CIMtrek_formName") String CIMtrek_formName,@RequestParam("fileUPload") MultipartFile uploadFile,HttpServletRequest request) {

        UtilService fileUploadService = new UtilService();
        if(!uploadFile.isEmpty()) {
            fileUploadService.saveFile(uploadFile, request.getRealPath(""));
        }
        ViewContent vc = new ViewContent();
        String HTML = vc.getContent(CIMtrek_xmlData, CIMtrek_formName);
        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
        ls.add(HTML);
        logger.info("Welcome  CIMtrek_Regional_Whse Add!");
        return new ModelAndView("form", "list", ls);
    }
```

file save method :

```
public void saveFile(MultipartFile uploadItem, String requestPath) {
        File dir;
        File file;
        try {
            String fileName = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;
            if (uploadItem.getSize() > 0) {
                inputStream = uploadItem.getInputStream();
                fileName = requestPath + "\\resources\\Attachment\\";
                dir = new File(fileName);
                if (!dir.exists()) {
                    dir.mkdirs();
                }
                fileName += uploadItem.getOriginalFilename();
                file = new File(fileName);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                int readBytes = 0;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
                while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) != -1) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                }
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Please help me to resolve this. I save file to a specified location when submitting the form.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many Windows programs add the bytes 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF at the start of any document saved as UTF-8. This is the UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode byte order mark (BOM), and is commonly referred to as a UTF-8 BOM, even though it is not relevant to byte order.An example of this flaw is internet explorer  which will render in standards mode only when it starts with a document type declaration.
So i guess you need to check and skip possible BOM bytes

```
String enc = "ISO-8859-1"; // or NULL to use systemdefault
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
     UnicodeInputStream uin = new UnicodeInputStream(fis, enc);
     enc = uin.getEncoding(); // check and skip possible BOM bytes
     InputStreamReader in;
     if (enc == null) in = new InputStreamReader(uin);
     else in = new InputStreamReader(uin, enc);
```

Sources: [UnicodeInputStream](http://koti.mbnet.fi/akini/java/unicodereader/UnicodeInputStream.java.txt)